# multiple user name and html using json error

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to send multiple username and html according to that . The problem is it works when only one username is being fetched from the database . But its not working if i am using it inside the loop .

My php code for that is .

```
$srch_txt=$_REQUEST['srch_txt'];
$frnd_srch_query=mysqli_query($con,"select friend_id from friend_list where login_id='$login_id' and status='3' ");
while($frnd_srch_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($frnd_srch_query))
{
$f_id=$frnd_srch_query_result['friend_id'];
$frnd_name_srch_query=mysqli_query($con,"select f_name,l_name from users_profile where user_id='$f_id' and f_name like '%$srch_txt%'");
$frnd_name_srch_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($frnd_name_srch_query);
$fname=$frnd_name_srch_query_result['f_name'];
$lname=$frnd_name_srch_query_result['l_name'];
$fullname=$fname.' '.$lname;
$html="<a href='profile.php?id=".$f_id."'>".$fullname."</a>";

 $list = array();
 $list[] = array('html' => $html ,'fullname' => $fullname);
 echo json_encode($list);

}
```

in the above if i dont use a loop only one data for username and html is sent and it work s but its not working if i use a loop . my jquery code to get it .

```
$.ajax({
url:"modules/tagging/ajax.php",
type:"POST",
data:datastring
}).done(function(data){
//alert(data);
var final_data = JSON.parse(data);

var html_resp=final_data[0]['html'];
$(".tag_search").html(html_resp);
//var html_fullname=final_data[0]["fullname"];
//var final_text=first_half+' '+html_fullname
//$(".update").val(final_text);

});
```

the result i get

```
[{"html":"<a href='profile.php?id=27'>deepak chauhan<\/a>","fullname":"deepak chauhan"}][{"html":"<a href='profile.php?id=28'>sumit saini<\/a>","fullname":"sumit saini"}]
```

the error i am getting in jquery is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing several distinct bits of JSON encoded data.  Instead, collect the data in a single array in your loop and then output the resulting array once.

Without looking particularly into what your code does, this would be an example of what I mean...

```
$srch_txt = $_REQUEST['srch_txt'];
$frnd_srch_query = mysqli_query($con,"select friend_id from friend_list where login_id='$login_id' and status='3' ");

$list = array();

while( $frnd_srch_query_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $frnd_srch_query ) )
{
  $f_id = $frnd_srch_query_result['friend_id'];
  $frnd_name_srch_query = mysqli_query($con,"select f_name,l_name from users_profile where user_id='$f_id' and f_name like '%$srch_txt%'");
  $frnd_name_srch_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($frnd_name_srch_query);
  $fname=$frnd_name_srch_query_result['f_name'];
  $lname=$frnd_name_srch_query_result['l_name'];
  $fullname=$fname.' '.$lname;
  $html="<a href='profile.php?id=".$f_id."'>".$fullname."</a>";

  $list[] = array('html' => $html ,'fullname' => $fullname);

}

echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: thank you . now the error is gone . Ill find a way to get data in jquery now